# Почему Auth::attempt возвращает false после редиректа?

Tags: php, laravel

Использую Laravel 5.2.
При отправки метод `Auth::attempt` возвращает `true` и после редиректит на роут `admin`

```
class LoginController extends Controller {

    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt($request->only(['login', 'password']))) {
            var_dump(Auth::check()); // true
            return redirect()->intended('admin');
        }

        return back();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У роута `admin` есть middleware

```
class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        var_dump(Auth::check()); // false

        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return view('login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И после редиректа метод `Auth::attempt` возвращает `false`, почему так происходит?

Comment: [Ау_те_нтификация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, какая у вас версия Laravel? Устанавливали с 0 или обновлялись? Перезаписывали ли вы методы в модели `User`? В частности метод `getAuthIdentifier()`?  Пробовали ли вы сбросить кэш: `php artisan cache:clear`?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно обернуть все роуты которые используют аутентификацию, куки, сессии в `middleware` `web`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::post('/login', [
        'uses' => 'LoginController@login',
        'as' => 'login'
    ]);

    Route::get('/login', [
        'uses' => 'LoginController@loginPage',
        'as' => 'loginPage'
    ]);

});
```

Comment: Странно, впервые слышу о таком решении. Что ж, хорошо, что заработало.

Comment: Это в laravel 5.2

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение